Out-of-process background task & NamedPipeServer in UWP
I created a out-of-process background task in which I download a HLS stream(m3u/m3u8) by using a LibVLCSharp library.
Platform is UWP
I have two different processes app and background task. App is host process in which I create a NamedPipeServer. The NamedClient is created and connected in background task. so background task is client proccess.
Code of creating PipeServer
            Task.Run(
                async () =>
                {
                    pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(
                        PipeName,
                        PipeDirection.InOut,
                        1,
                        PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                        PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

                    streamServer = new StreamString(pipeServer);

                    if (!isClientListening)
                    {
                        isClientListening = true;

                        ListenClient();
                    }
                });


Code of creating and connecting PipeClient
        if (!pipeClient?.IsConnected ?? true)
        {
            pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(
                ".",
                PipeName,
                PipeDirection.InOut,
                PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

            await pipeClient.ConnectAsync();

            streamClient = new StreamString(pipeClient);
        }

I get exception Pipe is broken in different places of code. When PipeServer try to write data in pipe or pipeClient try to read data from pipe. When an exception Pipe is broken
is thrown PipeServer.IsConnected property is false.
Example of actions after which the Pipe is broken

Click on button. Inside of method which handle a button click, PipeServer is created also Background Task is registered and after PipeClient is created and connected.
PipeClient starts waiting when pipeServer ends writing data.

Example code, how I read data by using PipeClient
        List<RecordTask> tasks = null;
        if (pipeClient != null)
        {
            streamClient ??= new StreamString(pipeClient);

            var json = streamClient.ReadString();
            tasks = DeserializeJsonToRecordTaskList(json);
        }

        return tasks;

Example code, how I write data by using PipeServer
        if (pipeServer != null)
        {
            if (!pipeServer.IsConnected)
            {
                await pipeServer.WaitForConnectionAsync();
            }

            streamServer ??= new StreamString(pipeServer);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tasks);
            streamServer.WriteString(json);
        }

Stack and exception which I get
Pipe is broken.
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.CheckConnectOperationsServer() + 0x77
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnectionCoreAsync(CancellationToken) + 0x1e
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnectionAsync(CancellationToken) + 0xc6
   at Iptv.Core.RecordProvider.<LoadServerRecordTasks>d__29.MoveNext() + 0x74

Pipe is broken.
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.CheckConnectOperationsServer() + 0x77
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnectionCoreAsync(CancellationToken) + 0x1e
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnectionAsync(CancellationToken) + 0xc6
   at Iptv.Core.RecordProvider.<SaveServerRecordTasks>d__20.MoveNext() + 0x9b
в RecordProviderErrors.txt

I can't reproduce problems on all machines. I tested on Win10 19045.4870 on one machine and problem isn't reproduced but on another machine with same Win10 19045.4870 problem is reproduced, so problem don't depend on from versions of Windows.
All information about NamedPipes which I used. StreamString class is presented in this documentation

You can try to put pipe WaitForConnectionAsync in try-catch, catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is broken, close the connection after catching the exception and wait for the connection again. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream?view=net-8.0#examples

@JunjieZhu-MSFT, thanks. It helped me
